# Will the miner be provided with reward if a hard fork occurs?

Tags: mining-reward, blockchain-fork, soft-fork

1. When will the miner be provide with reward(if at all) when a hard fork occurs?
2. When will the miner be provide with reward(if at all) when a soft fork occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miners are rewarded iff they produce valid blocks that become a part of the blockchain record. The reward is included in the block itself, so the only way to receive a block reward is by publishing a valid block to the network.

Miners cannot force a hardfork upon the network, doing so would just mean that the network's nodes would ignore those blocks, since they would be invalid by the network's rules. The hard fork blocks would be effectively creating a new network, that only(?) the miner is on, making the blocks worthless. If some users happened to join the hardfork network, so that both the legacy and hardfork networks remained active after the fork, then miners on either side of the fork would be creating blocks that contain rewards of some value.

A majority of miners can force a soft fork onto the network though, if they work to make all non-soft-fork-compliant blocks stale. In that case, any miner that wanted to participate in the network (ie, receive rewards) would need to create soft-fork-compliant blocks. If a minority of miners wants to activate a soft fork, they will not be able to do so. The minority could still mine softfork-compliant blocks, and receive the block rewards for them, but the rules of the softfork would not be enforced on the network at large.